Jenkins maven deploy
I have been doing house cleaning on a very old Jenkins Job repository
I found something I am not sure to understand correctly
On  one job configuration in the Invoke top-level Maven targets
I saw this:
clean deploy -P release -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=xxx -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=mycloud.jks -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStoreType=jks
What does it mean ? is there some keys stored somewhere (where ?) allowing the build to be deploy ?
Where can I found the deployment target (in the maven settings file maybe) ?

The keystore could be provided by Jenkins? The deployment target is defined by the distributionManagement in the pom file directly or in a parent pom file of your project?

I don't know where is the keystore. Do you know where jenkins is supposed to provide this info
